# Check the type of user logged in

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Basically My android app has three module and I am using Firebase:

1. Patient
2. Doctor
3. Guardian

I want to detect that the login user is either Doctor, Patient or Guardian. How is this possible in Android App?

Actually, I have tried a lot to solve this query but failed to do so please help me.

[image]

Comment: that logic seems really.... off to me. have you ever heard of polymorphism? ONE class for MANY instances? same goes for this. dont put them in different instances.... them them into a "users" instance and add a "type": "doctor" for example... so when you query the large node, you can pull them out by type...

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to if you save user type as a child, when user register.